# How to receive Postman binary files in Express.js?

Tags: express, postman, body-parser

I am wanting to post an image in the form of binary in Express.js. I am trying to get binary file option of postman in a express.js. but i am not able to get that body data in express api. how i can get binary body in a express api. [image: binary body]

Comment: Looks like you're using a GET request instead of a POST one, change the request type in Postman and see if it helps.

Comment: I have put wrong screenshot. i have also used post but it's not working.

Comment: Can you share what you're doing on the express side? How are you trying to get the data? And are you getting anything at all?

Comment: I have tried it with req,body and request.file but would not work.

Comment: **How** did you try it with `req.body`? Have you [read the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)? It says you need to provide body parsing middleware. What middleware are you using? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: **How* did you try it with `request.file`? That isn't even a property that is [documented for the request API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req). Are you expecting it to be added by something else? Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Change Get request to Post request and Use a raw body parser instead.

```
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(
    bodyParser.raw({ limit: '50mb', type: ['image/*'] })
);
```

After that if you request and check the log

```
console.log(req.body);
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Message is sent in multiple chunks. You need to use req.on and concatenate them.

Do something like this inside the controller:

```
const dataChunks: any = []; // Hold data chunks
let content: string | any = null; // Hold file string

req.on('data', (chunk) => {
   // Concatenate each chunk of the message
   dataChunks.push(chunk);
});
req.on('end', () => {
   // Create content
   content = Buffer.concat(dataChunks);

   // Do further processing in here + return HTTP status
});
```

This code will loop through all the chunks, concatenate them, and, on 'end', finish obtaining the file input and do the rest of the processing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.